# Get event / location / page - address

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the address from a public event, sometimes it returns the geocoords, sometimes the full address and sometimes just the venuename. I found on another thread, that there is some issue on the app auth token. so the user-auth-token could get the address and the app-auth-token not. is there any way to get the address always?

Comment: Can you give 3 example full url query which was only return geocords, full adress, venuename?

Comment: this one returns correct: eid: 533009473416123 / just geocords: 389089187841555 / just locationname: 634540989894031 - i have no clue why this is not working on that special event, most of them are ok.. and yep, they are all public..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For temporary purpose before the bug fix (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/554303337923393), you can do this:

```
select location from page where page_id IN (SELECT venue.id from event where eid=533009473416123)
```

Graph API Explore example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20location%20from%20page%20where%20page_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20venue.id%20from%20event%20where%20eid%3D533009473416123)

**You MUST use User Access Token**, because APP access token sometime only return venue name instead of venue id, such as event id 634540989894031.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, but i dont want the user to let me obtain create_event access.

Comment: @AntonKohlbauer No, it doesn't require create_event permission, i'm tested the query on Graph API Explorer with basic permission.